# Firebase push notification not working for IOS - Bad Request 400

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase push notifications services for both ios and android apps.

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); 

// Alternatively, provide the JSON authentication file directly.
$client->setAuthConfig('firebase/project_service.json');

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');

$httpClient = $client->authorize();

//Firebase project ID
$project = 'myProject';
```

Message Payload

```
Array
(
    [message] => Array
        (
            [notification] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Test Notification
                    [body] => Test body
                )

            [token] => 4136ADAC16BEAAC8E4A57CBFAB5859E93E5A9A9DB3CE12D047225C7648B74BE4
        )

)
```

```
$response = $httpClient->post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$project}/messages:send", ['json' => $message]);
```

For android it's working fine.
For IOS, notifications are working fine if i schedule campaign from console, but not working if i provide token from send test message option.

Same payload is working fine for android with android device token but not for IOS token.

On IOS side, received token from this code snippet

```
- (void)didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
    ALog(@"Push notification token registration success.");

    const char *data = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSMutableString *token = [NSMutableString string];
    
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
        [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
    }
    
    if (getTokenCallbackId != nil) {
        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus: CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:token];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.getTokenCallbackId];

        getTokenCallbackId = nil;
    }
}
```

APN key is also added in firebase cloud messaging tab. All pre reqs done.

Please help what could be the issue.

Thank you.

I have tried all the necessary steps from firebase guide

Comment: after you receive token, you need to send to google... which will give you google token which you will save in DB and send push on this google token...

Comment: Fahim Pakar, please see my question, i am already fetching token and saving in db and sending it in payload.

Comment: CDVPluginResult I believe will store the token. Right? But I believe here you are sending Apple token and not Google token....

Comment: Yes, i am using some notification plugin in IOS which is giving token to my server and i am saving it in database. I am not sure which token it is. Can you please tell me how can i receive correct one if it's not right?

Comment: What I know is after we get Apple token, we need to give it to Google, which in-return give us google token which we save in DB. Now while sending push, we send in google token which internally send token to apple based on the google-apple token they have linked... what i see is in your code, you are not sending apple token to google which is important...